# Adding a checkbox in a table cell

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

Is this possible?

I have a table with user accounts retrieved from a database. Then at the start of each column I would like to add a checkbox which if selected will select the account. I tried experimenting with it and I can't seem to put the checkbox inside the table. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 const int ColumnSelect = 0;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    //Get real data here.
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("count");                
    dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
    dt.Rows[0][0] = "5";

    GridView1.Columns.Add(new TemplateField());        
    BoundField b = new BoundField();
    GridView1.Columns.Add(b);
    b.DataField = "count";
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}


protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Header)
    {            
        e.Row.Cells[ColumnSelect].Controls.Add(new CheckBox());
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        //Could also use (CheckBox)row.Cells[ColumnSelect].FindControl if you give the checkboxes IDs when generating them.
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.Cells[ColumnSelect].Controls[0];

        if (cb.Checked)
        {
            //Do something here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But the data will be retrieved from the database.

Comment: What I want to do is if the checkbox from the column is checked then the column will be selected.